# Estimating the standard deviation of the constituent parts of a combined variable

Tags: standard-deviation

I have a random variable $Z$. Each measurement in $Z$ is in reality the sum of two other random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Both $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. They should have the same standard deviation. They should also have similar means if that assumption needs to be made.

Given that I can only measure $Z$, can I estimate the standard deviation of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: By your assumption, $\text{var}(Z) = \text{var}(X) + \text{var}(Y) = 2\sigma^2$. You can use the sample variance to estimate $2\sigma^2$, hence get an estimate of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know $\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and that $Z = X + Y$, then $\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y) = \text{Var}(Z) / 2$.  So you can estimate both by estimating $\text{Var}(Z)$.

Comment: Each sample of $Z$ is a sum of a sample of $X$ and sample of $Y$. Does this imply $Z=X+Y$? - I'm a little bit fuzzy on stats notation.

Comment: Gerald If you could observe the x-values and y-values, would $z_i=x_i+y_i$?

Comment: @Glen_b: Yes that's my situation.

Comment: Then yes, $Z=X+Y$